# WordPress - Elementor - Sticky ElementsKit Nav Menu - Mobile View not showing

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am working with the ElementsKit Nav Menu in Elementor. I just added a Sticky Header or technicly two since one will stay on top without being sticky and one will appear after an fixed offset.

The Problem is, the one that is fixed with an Offset doesn't show the Mobile Menu fully when opened. It only goes as far as the Header Element. I attached some Pictures and the used CSS.
Can someone provide a simple solution? Thanks

CSS USED:

```
.header-2 {
 transform: translatey(-80px);
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease!important;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease!important;
 transition: all .3s ease!important;
}


.elementor-sticky--effects.header-2  {
 height: auto!important;
 transform: translatey(0px);
}

.elementor-sticky--effects.header-1 {
 display: none!important;
}
```

https://i.gyazo.com/e86f901c7f8117eef2ec0f2f4100ecf6.png
https://i.gyazo.com/83a276a2727ce04c52ea78122ef5f20f.png

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the header is being covered by the elements further down in the page. You should increase the z-index of the element like so, and also make sure that there are no other elements with a z-index as high as .header-2.

```
.header-2 {
 transform: translatey(-80px);
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease!important;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease!important;
 transition: all .3s ease!important;
 z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: I added the z-index in the CSS and also in the Elementor Element, didn't work. The thing that is confusing me is that, in the normal sub Menu in Desktop View it works fine, yet in the mobile view not.